# Run a single Runner class through gradle command line - karate

Tags: gradle, karate

I have more than one runner class created in my src/test/java folder. When i run the gradle command by
gradle test -DcatsRunner
it runs all the Runner files inside the folder and not just one. How to run only one Runner file using gradle command line

gradle test -DcatsRunner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to run a single test case with gradle.

Running `gradle help --task test` will give you the following help message:

```
$ gradle help --task test
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.

> Task :help
Detailed task information for test

Path
     :test

Type
     Test (org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test)

Options
     --debug-jvm     Enable debugging for the test process. The process is started suspended and listening on port 5005.

     --fail-fast     Stops test execution after the first failed test.

     --tests     Sets test class or method name to be included, '*' is supported.

Description
     Runs the unit tests.

Group
     verification
```

The `--test` parameter is what you are looking for.

In you case:

```
gradle test --tests catsRunner
```

If you want to setup a more comprehensive test filtering, please read [the test filtering gradle documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html#test_filtering).

Comment: How could this be setup as a Gradle Task? I have a repository with 100's of runners and Scenarios and I'd like to group them by runners and/or tags. However I would like to see them listed in my Gradle Task View in my IDE if possible

Comment: Please formulate a new and detailed question.